# Resizing a small image into bigger image

Tags: python-3.x, data-science

I have a folder containing 5100 images in png format , each image having 32 * 32 pixels (height and width) . How can I resize the image in python by increasing its height and width(for image processing)? Also , will doing this can help my model improve the accuracy?

Comment: Increasing the image size won't increase the amount of information in each image.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python, you can use .resize() option to resize the image. This, as per my knowledge, won't have any impact on the accuracy